# Write $\cos(x)$ in terms of $\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Write $\cos(x)$ in terms of $\sin(x)$ if the terminal point $x$ is in quadrant IV.

I know $\cos^2(x)$ $= 1-\sin^2(x)$. And I know that cos is positive in quadrant IV. I am

guessing that the answer is $\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$  Can anyone help verify this answer?

Thank you!!

Comment: First, it is $\cos(x)^2 = 1-\sin(x)^2$. Not clear what you meant by "I know that...". also, the square root formula you write later is parenthesized wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, it's not quite correct. Let's start with the identity

$$\sin^2{x} + \cos^2{x} = 1 \implies \cos^2{x} = 1 - \sin^2{x}$$

In quadrant IV, $\cos{x}$ is positive, so taking a square root gives us

$$\cos{x} = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2{x}}$$

Answer (score -3):

$\cos x = 1 - 2 * \sin^2(x/2)$
prove:
\begin{align}
&=>1 - 2 * \sin^2(x/2) \\   
&= 1 - 2 * \sin(x/2) * \sin(x/2)  \\ 
&= 1 - 2 * \sqrt{((1-\cos x)/2)} * \sqrt{((1-\cos x)/2)} \quad \text{NOT: even sqrts are (-), (-)*(-)=(+)}  \\
&= 1 - 2 * (1-\cos x)/2 \\
&= 1 - 1 + \cos x  \\
&= \cos x \\
\end{align}